# Marketing Cloud Account Users' MFA Status

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, mfa

I can't figure out how to retrieve the MFA status of Marketing Cloud account users. I would like to know how many of our users have already enabled MFA. I can't find any objects with an MFA field or any reports in MC. I know that this is visible in the UI, but I would love to be able to access it via Automation Studio.

Has anyone been able to figure out a way to get this info.?

Comment: That would be helpful. I don't see a property for it on the AccountUser SOAP object, nor do I see any references to it in the REST endpoints that return User info.  It could be there's a internal REST endpoint that returns it, but that'll take some digging around with your browsers developer tools.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. I did poke around last night and couldn't find any REST routes in dev tools that bring back auth data with MFA status unfortunately.